# Get value from div to textbox

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to get the value from a div element to textbox?

My script codes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    barcode.setHandler(function(barcode) {
        $('#result').html(barcode);
    });
    barcode.init();
```

I show the result with the following code

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

I fail to get the div value into the textBox.

```
 <input type="text" id="result">
```

Comment: where is `barcode` defined?

Comment: With `input`s and `textarea`s, you need to set their `value` properties rather than their `innerHTML` properties.

Comment: Barcode definition is done before. there is no problem @larz

Comment: why did you declare `id` twice?

Comment: Both your `div` and `input` are have an `id` of result... This is invalid HTML.

Comment: Use one as class and one as id but don't use same id for multiple elements , are you trying something like this - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/yjomXp

Comment: the point of having id and classes is that id's are unique to every element, you need to change that

Comment: @zokanzi, posted my comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option

Avoid using same id for multiple elements , instead of that use class or two different ids or use one as class and for other use as id

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log( $('#result').text())
        $('.result').val( $('#result').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">1222</div>
<input type="text" class="result">
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/yjomXp

Answer (score 1):

Ids need to be unique on a given page; your `input` and `div` both have the same id.  To insert from the div to the input, first get the text inside the div, then apply that to the input using `.val()`.

```js
const foo = $('#foo').text();
$('#bar').val(foo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
  This is inside the div
</div>
<input type="text" id="bar"></input>
```